# How to query with partition key in Amazon DynamoDB using the AWS SDK for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to Amazon DynamoDB and I want to get records according to creator id. I made one partition key and after made query

```
 var params = {

    TableName: process.env.TABLE_PARTS,
     IndexName: "createdBy-index",
      KeyConditionExpression: "createdBy = :createdBy",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {":createdBy": "abus282jehbhwdubunids"}
      
   }
  
  const data = await db.query(params).promise();

  res.send(data);
```

But I am getting data = null

Answer (score -1):

To learn how to successfully use the AWS SDK for JavaScript to query Amazon DynamoDB tables, see the  ***AWS SDK for JavaScript DEV Guide***. Specifically refer to this topic:

[Amazon DynamoDB examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-examples.html)

See the example under ***Getting an item***.

This DEV guide has the information you need to successfully use this SDK.

Comment: For more extensive code examples, I recommend https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/tree/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/node.js